# Pass request as argument to service client vs. pass service client as argument to request

Tags: java, design, design-patterns, object-oriented, object-oriented-design

I need a design recommendation: I have a class that send a http request via another class `WebServiceHandler()`
I am hesitating between the following two implementations, which one to choose?which one is more accurate from OO point of view?

**First implementation:**

```
/* WebServiceHandler class is charged on sending http requests and getting responses */
public class WebServiceHandler()
{
    public boolean sendRequest(String method)
    {
        /*send a http request, get a response*/
    }
}

/* Step is modeling one request execution, on the main program I can have multiple steps to get a scenario like: connect to the server, send a get request, etc */
public class Step()
{
    private boolean result=false;
    private WebServiceHandler handler;

    public Step (WebServiceHandler handler)
    {
        this.handler= handler;
    }

    private void execute()
    {
        result = handler.sendRequest(this.httpMethod);
        /*this.httpMethod can be GET Http method for example*/
    }
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        handler= new WebServiceHandler();
        step= new Step(handler);
        step.execute();
    }
}
```

**Second Implementation:**

```
public class WebServiceHandler()
{
    public boolean sendRequest(String method)
    {
        /*send a http request, get a   response*/
    }

    public void executeStep(Step step)
    {
        result=sendRequest(step.getMethod());
        step.setResult(result);
    }
}

public class Step()
{
    private boolean result=false;

    setResult(String result){/*setter*/}
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        handler = new WebServiceHandler();
        step = new Step();
        handler.executeStep(step);
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly does the `WebServiceHandler` send a request in the `sendRequest` method? How does it know how to communicate? Using scalar types manipulation? The class has no dependencies, or at least they are not visible. Which is bad, because the class lies about its api. Check [Dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) before you move any further.

Comment: Can you elaborate what the function/'reason for existance' of `WebServiceHandler` and `Step` is?

Comment: @DavidPacker: thanks for your response, sendRequest() get its parameters from the Step class when it is called, I edited my question to show the dependency between the classes.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: thanks for your responses, I edited my question with the classes roles.

Comment: Could you indent the code properly? You are making the code hard to read for those who want to help.

Comment: Please read: [Design Review: on-topic or not?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6504)

Comment: Name the classes after what they expose/represent to its client - what it does should come from objects name indirectly - that's why there are `Dogs` and `Ducks`, but not `Barkers` and `Quackers` (these might be interfaces though, but `Quakeable` is more common approach). You would notice that (meaningless) `Step` in both implementations have different responsibilities and it cannot represent them both. It may represent a `Request` for `WebService` (not handler) or use/depend on some request to produce/controll response, but we're not able to decide what is the case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your description of the classes `Step` and `WebServiceHandler`, the `Step` class depends on the `WebServiceHandler` to be able to do its job, but not the other way around.
This makes that it should be possible to have/create a `WebServiceHandler` without having a `Step` instance.

Given how the direction of your dependencies lies, the first design option is the better one of the two.

To make it easier to test your code without needing access to a live web service, I would advise you to make an interface (`IWebServiceHandler`) for the `WebServiceHandler`. This interface is what the `Step` class should depend on. That way you can swap out the real `WebServiceHandler` for a dummy version while testing the `Step` class.

Comment: Thanks for your response, actually what makes me hesitant about the first implementation is that I can look at the class WebServiceHandler having the role of a controler in MVC pattern and Step being part of the Model. In this case the second implementation made more sense to me :s

Comment: The MVC pattern deals with *user interaction*, where the Controller receives events that are initiated by the user of the application. I honestly don't see how the WebServiceHandler as you have shown it fits in there. Don't be fooled into trying to apply a pattern everywhere. Design Patterns are common solutions to design problems that have been given a name to ease the communication when discussing a design.